# Calculating unmatching rows in partitioned table in hive

Tags: mysql, hive, partitioning, outer-join

I have a use-case where I have to calculate unmatching rows(excluding matching records) from two different partition's from a partitioned hive table.

Let's suppose there is a partitioned table called test which is partitioned on column as_of_date. Now to get the unmatching rows I tried with two option-
1.) 
`select count(x.item_id)
from
(select coalesce(test_new.item_id, test_old.item_id) as item_id
from
(select item_id from test where as_of_date = '2019-03-10') test_new
full outer join
(select item_id from test where as_of_date = '2019-03-09') test_old
on test_new.item_id = test_old.item_id
where coalesce(test_new.item_id,0) != coalesce(test_old.item_id,0)) as x;`

2.) I am creating a view first and then querying on that
`create view test_diff as
select coalesce(test_new.item_id, test_old.item_id) as item_id, coalesce(test_new.as_of_date, date_add(test_old.as_of_date, 1)) as as_of_date
from test test_new
full outer join test test_old
on (test_new.item_id = test_old.item_id and date_sub(test_new.as_of_date, 1) = test_old.as_of_date)
where coalesce(test_new.item_id,0) != coalesce(test_old.item_id,0);`

Then I am using query 
`select count(distinct item_id) from test_diff where as_of_date = '2019-03-10';`

Both the case are returning different count. In second option I am getting lesser count. Please provide any suggestion on why counts are different.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you taken care of test_new,test_old tables(filtered with as_of_date = '2019-03-10') in 2nd option.

1st option , you are using select clause count(X.item_id), where as 2nd option count(distinct). distinct might have reduced your item count in later option.

Comment: actually in both the options queries will return unique elements only as i am doing ```where coalesce(test_new.item_id,0) != coalesce(test_old.item_id,0)```

Comment: Only thing I can observe difference is `date_sub(test_new.as_of_date, 1) = test_old.as_of_date)` in view join condition